# How to Append data to a combobox

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I need to insert data to a combobox so i do an append as defined in this lines :

```
fd = open(files,'rb')
data=fd.readlines()

for i in data[]:
    item=i.strip()
    if item is not None:
       combobox.Append(item)
fd.close
```

Even data insert the selection still void
please can you tell me how to set a selection a value from the items read.
as like as selection contain first element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
combobox.SetSelection(0)  # select first item
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this probably doesn't answer your question, but I recommend you close the file connection once you're done using it.

```
fd = open(files,'rb')
data=fd.readlines()

#Close the connection, you're done using it!
fd.close

#Now do what you want with data.
for i in data[]:
    item=i.strip()
    if item is not None:
       combobox.Append(item)
```